# Differential equation question on oscillations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> For any constant $k$, show that any solution of the equation$$x^2y''-xy'+(e^x-kx^2\sin x)y=0$$has infinitely many positive zeros.

From what I've learnt, I managed to convert the equation into its normal form, i.e.$$u''+\left(\dfrac{e^x-kx^2\sin x-\frac{3}{4}}{x^2}\right)u=0$$Then I am supposed to find some $m>0$ such that $\dfrac{e^x-kx^2\sin x-\frac{3}{4}}{x^2}\ge m^2$. But, I have problem finding such an $m$. Am I on the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the long run behavior of the coefficient of $u$. For large $x$ you basically have $u'' + e^x/x^2 u$. Since that is positive and monotone increasing you know that there exists an $X$ and $m$ such that for all $x>X$ we have $e^x/x^2 > m^2$. Incidentally this is a really cool way of demonstrating that you have an infinite number of roots.

Comment: @Spencer Thnx, I understood what you meant. What if I want to show that the distance between the zeros converges to $0$ eventually?

Comment: The solutions to $u''+m^2 u=0 $ are oscillatory sines and cosines with angular frequency $m$. You can think of the $e^x/x^2$ as being a variable frequency that is getting shorter and shorter (i.e. the oscillations are becoming more rapid). I would imagine the key to proving the distance between roots converging to $0$ lies in that somewhere.